# Ajax comes back as success but the action is "never" called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am helping with a plugin build on Wordpress and am a bit stuck on what should be a pretty basic ajax call. I am trying to take the object and run it through the method 'grab_object_from_ajax_call' however the method never runs and I am stumped on why it is not happening. This is the javascript portion of my code: (am I calling the wrong action?)

```
var billingFormOld = new BillingForm("example@email", "kyle", "123 address street", "thisCity");
$(window).on("mousedown", function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
      'action': 'grab_object_from_ajax_call',
      'billingFormOld': billingFormOld
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr){
    console.log(xhr);
    }
  });
});
```

Here are the two methods that should be used to make it work. Adding the action method is ran because I am calling it when the plugin constructs.

```
function formToBaseAjaxHandler(){
        add_action('wp_ajax_grab_object_from_ajax_call', array($this, 'grab_object_from_ajax_call'));//Start AJAX request Handler
    }
```

And this is the method that needs to run next but it does not:

```
function grab_object_from_ajax_call(){
    error_log("does this get called"); //never see this in log
    $oldBillingForm = (object) $_REQUEST['billingFormOld'];//grabbing the object 
    $this->enter_object_properties_to_database($oldBillingForm);
    die();
}
```

I am getting response of '0' in my console with a success message so I have a feeling it is within my php code. Any pointers to what might be stopping this from working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks stack overflow! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you add ajax actions to your plugin.php or functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

in your case:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_grab_object_from_ajax_call', 'grab_object_from_ajax_call_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_grab_object_from_ajax_call', 'grab_object_from_ajax_call_callback' );

function grab_object_from_ajax_call_callback(){
  error_log("does this get called"); //never see this in log
  $oldBillingForm = (object) $_REQUEST['billingFormOld'];//grabbing the object 
  $this->enter_object_properties_to_database($oldBillingForm);
  die();
}
```